# Use Django with Parse.com

Tags: python, django, django-models, parse-platform

I'm working on a django website which will have an equivalent app.We figured with my team that we should use **Parse.com** so as to have a single "database" for the two implementations.

Now here comes a dilemma. Django have a beautiful ORM and some great apps which can help with lot of things. So it would be fantastic if i could use Django-ORM but i can't find a way to achieve that using **Parse.com** as my database. I came across **Django-ROA** but i really can't figure out how to make it works.

What is good way to handle the problem ? Or if anyone knows how to make Django-ROA work with a BaaS like Parse, i'll be thrilled to hear it.

Thank you in advance !

**EDIT :**

If i can't use anything  that could enable me to use django session features i will keep using ParsePy. Basically at signup/login, user informations will be stored on Parse.com and any user authenticated will be redirected to a dashboard where he can see his profile information, and when he goes on the store he has to be recognized as a registered user...etc What would be a secure way to achieve that ? Signed cookies ? Certificates ? I'm all ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally ended up using ParsePy. But i set up a db in Django just to handle sessions server side. That's what i would recommend for any django user who uses Parse.com. You can't have Django ORM but ParsePy looks good. 
Store Parse session token with Django implemented session logic (very simple to use) and you're good to go. Other security measures include setting Https and SSL on your website domain.

**EDIT**: 
 **little more explanation on how to achieve this**

So you've got to enable [django sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/) thru your django settings.
Then you want to store the current Parse user sessionToken in the django session. So somewhere in your custom login view you'd do something like this:
```

```
request.session['ParseSession'] = parse_logged_user.sessionToken
```

From now on anytime you want to retrieve current user info, you'd do something like this:

```
from parse_rest.connection import SessionToken
with SessionToken(request.session['ParseSession']):
    current_user = User.current_user()
```

This is the most straightforward way to accomplish this. Hopefully you'd end up writing a middleware to do this and also check for the session key availability.

Comment: Can you give a quick sketch of what this looks like in Django? I know how to use ParsePy but don't know how to wrap Django's session logic around it.

Comment: Thanks. I had actually figured it out in the intervening days, but this will be really useful to anyone else in my position (and I think there will be some, with Parse's sunset process nearly complete).

Comment: Sorry to revive an old question, but is there a way to log a user out or delete the session token from the parse_rest module? I haven't been able to find it (if it does exist).

Comment: To log a user out you would just need to delete the token from the [django] session you keep. There is no need to "logout" at parse level.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the  Python client for the Parse REST API provided by Parse.com? 
Here is link for you.
https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy

Hope it works. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, that's what i use now but for some reasons i feel like i'm missing something better, something that could enable me to use django session features and save me the hassle of finding a good way to securely handle user "session" in a RESTful way. Basically user informations will be stored on Parse.com and any user authenticated will be redirected to a dashboard where he can see his profile information, and when he goes on the store he has to be recognized as a registered user...etc What would be a secure way to achieve that ?